# Django Admin M2M filter verbose_name on listing page

Tags: django, admin

I have one ManyToMany model that I am using for two fields on a Model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    deposit    = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMethod, related_name="deposit")
    withdrawal = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMethod, related_name="withdrawal")
```

Then in my admin file I have this:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('deposit', 'withdrawal',)
```

The only problem with this is that on the filter on the listing page (in the right column). It says "By Payment Method", instead of "By Deposit" and "By Withdrawal".

Comment: What version of Django are you using? It seems that subclassing the SimpleListFilter method is present only in the development version, not 1.3

Comment: 1.4. I think it might be a bug. It shouldn't be necessary to subclass any Filter class. I have added a bug report. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15221

This is a workaround (for version 1.4). It's ugly, but at least it's not monkey patching:

```
from django.contrib.admin import RelatedFieldListFilter
from django.contrib.admin.util import get_model_from_relation

class WorkAroundListFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):

    def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
        super(RelatedFieldListFilter, self).__init__(
            field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)

        other_model = get_model_from_relation(field)
        self.lookup_title = field.verbose_name
        rel_name = other_model._meta.pk.name
        self.lookup_kwarg = '%s__%s__exact' % (self.field_path, rel_name)
        self.lookup_kwarg_isnull = '%s__isnull' % (self.field_path)
        self.lookup_val = request.GET.get(self.lookup_kwarg, None)
        self.lookup_val_isnull = request.GET.get(
                                      self.lookup_kwarg_isnull, None)
        self.lookup_choices = field.get_choices(include_blank=False)
        self.title = self.lookup_title


class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('deposit', WorkAroundListFilter), 
        ('withdrawal', WorkAroundListFilter),
    )
```